# 404 file not found my node server

Tags: html, css, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to learn the MEAN stack and was following a project build building a simple chat app.

When i try to start my node server i get this error as my angular partials are not loading

```
> start@0.0.0 start C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\chirpse\start
> node ./bin/www

GET / 304 27.899 ms - -
GET /public/javascripts/chirpApp.js 404 43.724 ms - 1714
GET /public/stylesheets/style.css 404 45.081 ms - 1714
GET /public/javascripts/chirpApp.js 404 4.613 ms - 1714
GET /public/stylesheets/style.css 404 4.450 ms - 1714
```

I am sure my paths must be wrong in my index.ejs but i can't seem to figure out how to correct them. I would appreciate if somebody could take a look.

Index.ejs

[image: index.ejs]

File structure
[image: File Structure Img]

Comment: I think your index.html and javascript are in same folder i.e. "public" . Isn't it?

Comment: I managed to find a fix. My index.html was pointing up a directory when it did not need to. Thanks

Comment: Exactly the point I was trying to make :)